How to set loadingTemplate inside custom Nuxt Module
I'm building a nuxt module, and want to set loadingTemplate within this module.
What I tried so far is modifying devServer inside module like below (But no luck)
import { loadingTemplate } from './loadingTemplate'

export default defineNuxtModule<ModuleOptions>({
    ...
    async setup (options, nuxt) {
        nuxt.options.devServer = {
            ...nuxt.options.devServer,
            loadingTemplate
        }
    }
})

I've also tried doing it via hooks:
import { loadingTemplate } from './loadingTemplate'

export default defineNuxtModule<ModuleOptions>({
    ...
    async setup (options, nuxt) {
        nuxt.hook('ready', (nuxtApp) => {
            nuxtApp.devServer = {
                ...nuxt.devServer,
                loadingTemplate
            }
        })
    }
})

I've tried different hooks: ready, listen
Can someone point me in correct direction on how to use custom loadingTemplate that will be set from my nuxt module?

Maybe no solution - the loading screen shows before loading modules

Try using Nuxt hooks. If that doesn't work, you can check out this link
async setup(options, nuxt) {
    // modules:before hook to set the custom loading template
    nuxt.hook('modules:before', () => {
        nuxt.options.loading = {
            template: loadingTemplate
        };
    });
}


First, define your custom loading template plugin:
Create a file named loadingTemplate.js in your module directory.
Then define your custom loading template content within this file.
// loadingTemplate.js

export default
  <div>
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
  </div>

Next, try updating your Nuxt module to use the custom loading template:
Modify your module file to include the custom loading template.
// Your Nuxt module file

import loadingTemplate from './loadingTemplate.js';

export default defineNuxtModule<ModuleOptions>({
    ...
    extendPlugins (plugins) {
        plugins.push({
            src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'loadingTemplate.js'),
            fileName: 'loadingTemplate.js'
        })
    }
})

I hope this helps you.

import { readFileSync } from 'fs'
import { resolve } from 'path'

export default defineNuxtModule<ModuleOptions>({
    async setup (options, nuxt) {
        // Read your custom loading template file
        const loadingTemplatePath = resolve(__dirname, 'loading.html')
        const loadingTemplate = readFileSync(loadingTemplatePath, 'utf-8')

        // Use the `listen` hook to apply the custom loading template
        nuxt.hook('listen', (server, { host, port }) => {
            if (nuxt.options.dev) {
                const originalCreateServer = server.createServer

                server.createServer = function (...args) {
                    const app = originalCreateServer.apply(this, args)

                    app.use((req, res, next) => {
                        if (req.url === '/_loading') {
                            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
                            res.end(loadingTemplate)
                        } else {
                            next()
                        }
                    })

                    return app
                }
            }
        })
    }
})

